# Use USB Wifi Adapter with virtual machine

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, virtualbox

I want to use my usb wifi dongle on my virtual machine (kali linux). I installed the extension pack and activated the usb 2.0 controllers. Also i add my wifi usb dongle as a filter. The kali vm recognize the wifi adapter, also i can see it with `ifconfig` (as wlan0).
In my network settings i have NAT with Intel Pro/1000 MT Desktop activated. All in all - i can use the internet connection with NAT (virtual LAN over my integrated wireless card), but my wifi adapter won't find any wifi networks.